# StiffSystem or Singularity - a system of second order ODEs in the problem of geodesics

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, singularity

I would be extremely grateful for any help regarding the following code I wrote and the errors it produces. In this code I am investigating the behaviour of a massive particle trapped in the vicinity of the gravitational Bessel wave vertex.

I am really sorry for the lengthy expressions - I have no idea how to shorten it in any way that would help significantly.
The table defined below is the right hand side of the geodesic equation. I have checked its correctness with my advisor, obtaining the same result as he did.
The parameter "a" refers to the amplitude of the wave, while "b" and "c" are responsible for the wavevector quantities.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
coords = {t, x, y, z}
n = Length[coords];

geodesic = {BesselJ[3, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] (-((a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) (x')^2)/(x^2 +
               y^2)^(3/2)) + (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) (y')^2)/(x^2 +
             y^2)^(3/2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) + (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (-3 x^2 y + y^3) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))) + 
  BesselJ[0, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (4 a b Sqrt[
       b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - c z] x' z' + 
     4 a b Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 Sin[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - c z] y' z') + 
  BesselJ[2, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (x^2 - y^2) x' z')/(x^2 +
            y^2) + (8 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y y' z')/(x^2 + y^2)) -
      Sin[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((8 a b^3 Sqrt[
              b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y x' z')/(x^2 + 
             y^2)) - (4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (-x^2 + 
             y^2) y' z')/(x^2 + y^2))) + 
  BesselJ[1, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (x')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 y x' y')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (y')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (4 a b^2 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x (z')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a Sqrt[
              b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
               2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (x')^2)/
           Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 x x' y')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (y')^2)/
         Sqrt[
          x^2 + y^2] + (4 a b^2 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y (z')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])), 
 BesselJ[4, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((a b^5 x y (-3 x^2 + 
             y^2) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) + (a b^5 y^2 (-3 x^2 + 
             y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (a b^5 x y (x^2 + 
             5 y^2) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b^5 x^2 (x^2 - 
             3 y^2) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) + (a b^5 x y (x^2 - 
             3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (a b^5 (x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 - 
             2 y^4) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2))) + 
  BesselJ[3, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((2 a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) t' x')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) + (3 a b^4 y (-3 x^2 y + y^3) (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(5/2) + (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) t' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (6 a b^4 x y (-3 x^2 + y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) + (3 a b^4 (-2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + y^4) (y')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(5/2) - (2 a b^4 c y (-3 x^2 + y^2) x' z')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a b^4 x (4 c y^2 + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) y' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((2 a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) t' x')/(x^2 +
               y^2)^(3/2)) - (3 a b^4 x y (x^2 - 3 y^2) (x')^2)/(x^2 +
             y^2)^(5/2) + (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) t' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (6 a b^4 x^2 (x^2 - 3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) + (3 a b^4 x y (5 x^2 + y^2) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) + (2 a b^4 c x (x^2 - 3 y^2) x' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (2 a b^4 y (-2 c (x^2 - y^2) + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) y' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))) +
   BesselJ[1, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x t' x')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 y t' y')/
         Sqrt[
          x^2 + y^2] + (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x^2 x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (2 a c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x x' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (c^4 + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] - b^2 (b^2 + 2 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c^2 (-2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c (-4 b^2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + (b^2 + c^2)^(3/2))) y y' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (4 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((2 a Sqrt[
              b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
               2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y t' x')/
           Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 
             2 c^2 + 2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y^2 (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 x t' y')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (2 (b^2 + c^2) x^2 + (3 b^2 + 
                c^2) y^2 + c^2 (2 x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 x^2 + y^2)) (y')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y x' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (b^4 + c^4 + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + 2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c (4 b^2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + (b^2 + c^2)^(3/2))) x y' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (4 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y^2 (z')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2))) + 
  BesselJ[2, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] (-((a b x y ((-3 b^4 + 
                  2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 + (2 b^2 + 
                   c^2)^2 y^2 + c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
               4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
               4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
               2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                  y^2)) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
                y^2)^2)) - (a b y^2 ((-3 b^4 + 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 + (2 b^2 + 
                 c^2)^2 y^2 + c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (a b x y ((2 b^2 + c^2)^2 x^2 + (5 b^4 + 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                y^2)) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) - (8 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y t' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (2 a b^3 (-3 c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a b x^2 (c^4 x^2 + (-3 b^4 - 
                  2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^2 + 
               c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 8 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) - 
               2 c^2 (b^2 - 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                  y^2)) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
                y^2)^2)) - (a b x y (c^4 x^2 + (-3 b^4 - 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 8 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) - 
             2 c^2 (b^2 - 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - 
        1/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) a b ((2 b^2 + c^2)^2 x^4 + (3 b^4 + 
              2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + 3 (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 y^2 + 
           2 (-b^4 + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^4 + 
           4 c Sqrt[
             b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) ((2 b^2 + c^2) x^2 + 
              2 (b^2 + c^2) y^2) + 
           2 c^2 (x^2 + y^2) ((b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) x^2 + 
              6 (b^2 + c^2) y^2) + c^4 (x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + 2 y^4) + 
           4 c^3 Sqrt[
             b^2 + c^2] (x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + 
              2 y^4)) (y')^2 + (4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (x^2 - y^2) t' z')/(x^2 +
            y^2) - (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (2 a b^3 (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (-Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x^2 + 
             c (x^2 - 2 y^2)) (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2))) + 
  BesselJ[0, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) + (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y^2 x' y')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) + (2 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x^2 (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) + (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y x' y')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 ((3 b^2 + c^2) x^2 + 
             2 (b^2 + c^2) y^2 + c^2 (x^2 + 2 y^2) + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + 2 y^2)) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) + 
        4 a b Sqrt[
          b^2 + c^2] (c + 
            Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 t' z' - (2 a b (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (b^2 x^2 + 2 c^2 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2))), 
 BesselJ[4, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b^5 x y (5 x^2 + 
             y^2) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) - (a b^5 x^2 (x^2 - 
             3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (a b^5 x y (x^2 - 
             3 y^2) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a b^5 (-2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + 
               y^4) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2)) - (a b^5 x y (-3 x^2 + 
             y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (a b^5 y^2 (-3 x^2 + 
             y^2) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2))) + 
  BesselJ[3, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((2 a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) t' x')/(x^2 +
             y^2)^(3/
            2) - (3 a b^4 (x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 - 2 y^4) (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(5/2) + (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) t' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (6 a b^4 x y (x^2 - 3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) - (3 a b^4 x^2 (x^2 - 3 y^2) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) + (2 a b^4 y (4 c x^2 + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) x' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (2 a b^4 c x (x^2 - 3 y^2) y' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2)) + Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((2 a b^4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) t' x')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) - (3 a b^4 x y (x^2 + 5 y^2) (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(5/2) - (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (-3 x^2 y + y^3) t' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (6 a b^4 y (-3 x^2 y + y^3) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) + (3 a b^4 x y (-3 x^2 + y^2) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/
            2) - (2 a b^4 x (2 c (x^2 - y^2) + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) x' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a b^4 c (-3 x^2 y + y^3) y' z')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2))) + BesselJ[1, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((2 a Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 y t' x')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 ((3 b^2 + c^2) x^2 + 
             2 (b^2 + c^2) y^2 + c^2 (x^2 + 2 y^2) + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + 2 y^2)) (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) - (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x t' y')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x^2 (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/

            2) - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (b^4 + c^4 + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + 2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c (4 b^2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + (b^2 + c^2)^(3/2))) y x' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (2 a c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (4 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x^2 (z')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((2 a Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^4 x t' x')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y t' y')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y^2 x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (c^4 + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] - b^2 (b^2 + 2 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c^2 (-2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) + 
             c (-4 b^2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] + (b^2 + c^2)^(3/2))) x x' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] - (2 a c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y y' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (4 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2))) + 
  BesselJ[2, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a b x y ((5 b^4 + 
                  2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 + (2 b^2 + 
                   c^2)^2 y^2 + c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
               4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
               4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
               2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                  y^2)) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
                y^2)^2)) + (a b x^2 ((2 b^2 + c^2)^2 x^2 + (-3 b^4 + 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (a b x y ((2 b^2 + c^2)^2 x^2 + (-3 b^4 + 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 4 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             4 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c^2 (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                y^2)) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) + (8 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y t' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (2 a b^3 (-3 c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (1/(2 (x^2 + 
               y^2)^2) a b (-2 (b^4 - (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^4 + (3 b^4 + 
              2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + 
              3 (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 y^2 + (2 b^2 + c^2)^2 y^4 + 
           4 c Sqrt[
             b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + 
              y^2) (2 (b^2 + c^2) x^2 + (2 b^2 + c^2) y^2) + 
           2 c^2 (x^2 + 
              y^2) (6 (b^2 + c^2) x^2 + (b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) y^2) + 
           c^4 (2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + y^4) + 
           4 c^3 Sqrt[
             b^2 + c^2] (2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + 
              y^4)) (x')^2 + (a b x y ((-3 b^4 - 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 + c^4 y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 8 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) - 
             2 c^2 (b^2 - 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (a b y^2 ((-3 b^4 - 
                2 b^2 (b^2 + c^2) + (b^2 + c^2)^2) x^2 + c^4 y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 8 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) - 
             2 c^2 (b^2 - 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + 
                y^2)) (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^2) - (4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (-x^2 + 
             y^2) t' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (2 a b^3 (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (-Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] y^2 + 
             c (-2 x^2 + y^2)) (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2))) + 
  BesselJ[0, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) - (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x^2 x' y')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (3 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
             y^2)) - (2 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a b (c + 
                Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (2 (b^2 + c^2) x^2 + (3 b^2 + 
                  c^2) y^2 + c^2 (2 x^2 + y^2) + 
               2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (2 x^2 + y^2)) (x')^2)/(2 (x^2 + 
               y^2))) - (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y x' y')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (a b (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (-b^2 + 2 c^2 + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y^2 (y')^2)/(2 (x^2 + y^2)) - 
        4 a b Sqrt[
          b^2 + c^2] (c + 
            Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 t' z' + (2 a b (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 (b^2 y^2 + 2 c^2 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) (z')^2)/(x^2 + y^2))), 
 BesselJ[3, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((a b^4 x (2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 - y^2) + 
             c (x^2 + y^2)) (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] y (-3 x^2 + y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a b^4 x (4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] y^2 + 
             c (x^2 + y^2)) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((a b^4 y (4 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] x^2 + 
             c (x^2 + y^2)) (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - (2 a b^4 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] x (x^2 - 3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a b^4 y (2 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (-x^2 + y^2) + 
             c (x^2 + y^2)) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))) + 
  BesselJ[0, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (4 a b Sqrt[
          b^2 + c^2] (c + 
            Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 t' x' + (4 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x^2 x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (4 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-4 a b Sqrt[
          b^2 + c^2] (c + 
            Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^3 t' y' - (4 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (4 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y^2 y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2))) + 
  BesselJ[2, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] (Cos[
       Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] ((4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (x^2 - y^2) t' x')/(x^2 +
            y^2) - (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (-x^2 + 
             y^2) (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 + (8 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y t' y')/(x^2 + 

           y^2) - (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (x^2 - 
             3 y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (16 a b^3 (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x^2 y (y')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (4 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x^2 x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (4 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2)) - 
     Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((8 a b^3 Sqrt[
              b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y t' x')/(x^2 + 
             y^2)) - (16 a b^3 (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x y^2 (x')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 - (4 a b^3 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) (-x^2 + 
             y^2) t' y')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) - (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (-3 x^2 + 
             y^2) x' y')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (8 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (-x^2 + 
             y^2) (y')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^2 + (4 a b^3 (c + 
              Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y x' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2) + (4 a b^3 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y^2 y' z')/(x^2 + 
           y^2))) + 
  BesselJ[1, 
    b Sqrt[x^2 + 
       y^2]] (-Sin[
        Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
         c z] ((a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (7 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 b^2 (-(b^2 - 2 (b^2 + c^2)) x^2 + (b^2 + 
                   2 (b^2 + c^2)) y^2)) (x')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (2 a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (5 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             b^2 ((-3 b^2 + 2 (b^2 + c^2)) x^2 + (b^2 + 
                   2 (b^2 + c^2)) y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) - (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (4 b^4 y^2 + 
             c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (3 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) (y')^2)/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) + (8 a b^2 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x t' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (8 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y x' z')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/
            2) - (8 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x^2 y' z')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) - (4 a b^2 c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x (z')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + 
     Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] t - 
        c z] (-((a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (4 b^4 x^2 + 
               c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
               c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (3 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
               c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2)) (x')^2)/(x^2 +
               y^2)^(3/2)) + (2 a (c + 
             Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) x (c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (5 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             b^2 ((b^2 + 2 (b^2 + c^2)) x^2 + (-3 b^2 + 
                   2 (b^2 + c^2)) y^2)) x' y')/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (a (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]) y (c^4 (x^2 + y^2) + 
             3 c^3 Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c Sqrt[b^2 + c^2] (7 b^2 + c^2) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             c^2 (2 b^2 + 3 (b^2 + c^2)) (x^2 + y^2) + 
             2 b^2 ((b^2 + 2 (b^2 + c^2)) x^2 - (b^2 - 
                   2 (b^2 + c^2)) y^2)) (y')^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/
            2) + (8 a b^2 Sqrt[
            b^2 + c^2] (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y t' z')/
         Sqrt[x^2 + 
           y^2] + (8 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y^2 x' z')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/
            2) - (8 a b^2 (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 x y y' z')/(x^2 + 
            y^2)^(3/2) - (4 a b^2 c (c + Sqrt[b^2 + c^2])^2 y (z')^2)/
         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]))};
```

To find the solution, I use the following procedure.
First I take the values of the parameters to be:

```
b = 1
c = 20
a = 10^(-6)
```

Then I numerically evaluate them:

```
ngeodesic = N[geodesic];
```

And use the following procedure in order to obtain a solution for all the coordinates. First I calculate the first component of the four-velocity at parameter value equal to zero - this gives the remaining initial value for the NDSolve. After the NDSolve piece of code, I list the four-velocity vector's length to check if the system evolves the way it should.

```
minkowskimetric = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, 1}}

computeSoln[maxτi_, ivsi_, icsi_] := 
 Block[{ivs, ics, i, χ, tmp, soln},
  ics = icsi;
  ivs = Join[{χ}, ivsi];
  tmp = minkowskimetric;
  tmp = ivs.(tmp.ivs);
  χslv = Solve[tmp == uinvar, χ];
  ivs[[1]] = Last[χ /. χslv];
  deq = Table[
    coords[[i]]''[τ] == (ngeodesic[[i]] /. 
       Join[Table[coords[[i]]' -> coords[[i]]'[τ], {i, 1, n}], 
        Table[coords[[i]] -> coords[[i]][τ], {i, 1, n}]]), {i, 1,
      n}];
  deq = Join[deq, Table[coords[[i]]'[0] == ivs[[i]], {i, 1, n}], 
    Table[coords[[i]][0] == ics[[i]], {i, 1, n}]];
  soln = NDSolve[deq, coords, {τ, 0, maxτi}];
  soln]
uinvar = -1;

udotu[solni_, τval_] := Block[{xα, uα},
  xα = 
   Table[coords[[i]][τ] /. solni, {i, 1, n}] // Flatten;
  uα = D[xα, τ];
  xα = xα /. τ -> τval;
  uα = uα /. τ -> τval;
  uα.(minkowskimetric.uα)]
coordlist[τin_] := 
 Table[ToString[coords[[i]]] <> 
   "=" <> {ToString[coords[[i]][τin] /. soln // First]}, {i, 1, 
   n}]
```

In what follows I use the initial values that actually yield some result. The behaviour looks like something obtained by my advisor, who used Maple.
The ivs table is the initial velocities table - (x,y,z) components. The ics table is the table of initial coordinates (t,x,y,z).

```
maxτ = 40
ivs = {0.01, 0.01, 0.1};
ics = {0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0};
soln = computeSoln[maxτ, ivs, ics];
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[ {coords[[2]][τ], coords[[3]][τ], 
    coords[[4]][τ]}] /. soln, {τ, 0, maxτ}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[coords[[i]][τ] /. soln, {i, 1, n}]], {τ,
   0, maxτ}, PlotStyle -> Table[Hue[(i - 1)/n], {i, 1, n}], 
 PlotLegends -> coords, AxesLabel -> {"τ", "Coordinate"}]
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[ {coords[[2]][τ], coords[[3]][τ]}] /. 
  soln, {τ, 0, maxτ}]


Join[{{"", "", "", "u*u values"}}, 
  Table[{"τ=", ToString[i], "->", udotu[soln, i]}, {i, 0, 
    maxτ, maxτ/5}]] // TableForm
```

The problem begins when I try to change the initial conditions to, let's say:

```
ics = {0, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0};
```

In that case (and literally any other) I get the error:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At τ == 0.34526573966566704`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

My advisor (who does not use Mathematica) gets very nice results for almost any imaginable parameters - since the physical problems only occur on the z coordinate axis.
I am at loss at the moment - I suspect that the very small values (e.x. the amplitude "a") are the cause for the problem. However, I have no idea if I could even rescale all the quantities used here - the problem is, after all, highly nonlinear, even in the parameters a,b,c.

EDIT:

I put the whole code here:
[besselgravcart](https://pastebin.com/dWaqNrxw)

[besselgravcylindrical](https://pastebin.com/j4a5vApV)

[besselgravconstants](https://pastebin.com/Jqztk58T)

Comment: With default options, `NDSolve` becomes numerically unstable for `ics[[2]]` larger than about `0.1189`.  `Method->"StiffnessSwitching"` does not help.  Neither does increasing `WorkingPrecision` (with all inputs rationalized).  Perhaps, better choices of other options would.  By the way, comments by other experienced users suggest that Maple is better than Mathematica at solving some ODEs.

Comment: Does a symbolic expression exist for the inner turning point of the solution in `{coords[[2]][τ], coords[[3]][τ]}` space?  Alternatively, does the solution satisfy any conservation laws?

Comment: What do you mean by "a symbolic expression for the inner turning point of the solution"? I do not quite understand. Thanks for the question about the conservation laws! That might be an excellent way to help the stability.

Comment: I would like to write the full expression for the metric in this post or the original post, but there is not enough space. I have however checked that there is a Killing vector:$K = \partial_{t} + \frac{\omega}{kz}\partial_{z}$. The conserved quantity associated with it (I assume the length is calculated with the Minkowski metric - or should I do it with the full metric?) is: $const = \eta_{\mu\nu}K^{\mu}U^{\nu}=...=-\dot{t}+ \frac{\omega}{kz}\dot{z}$. I am currently in the process of trying to find the second (perhaps existing...) Killing field.

Comment: Solutions in `x - y` space come in from large `r`, skim a circle of constant `r` for some distance and then go out to large `r` again.  So, I speculate that this circle of constant `r` is a separatrix.  If so, then infinitesimal errors in the computation near the separatrix would cause the computation to fail catastrophically.  First integrals of the motion might help to alleviate this problem.  Can the equations be rewritten conveniently in terms or `r` and `theta` instead of `x` and `y` (i.e., in cylindrical coordinates)?  In other words, is the metric axisymmetric?

Comment: As for the Killing field, of course I meant: $const=-\dot{t}+\frac{\sqrt{c^{2}+b^{2}}}{c}\dot{z}$. I will now try to edit the original post so as to fit the expressions for the metric. What should I do if I lack the space? Should I use the "answer your question" option?

Comment: Do not write part of your question as an answer.  It will be deleted.  Instead, post the lengthy code on the internet and provide a reference in the question.  Also, your last comment tells me that `t` is a linear function of `z`, so one of the four ODEs is not needed.  Correct?  Is the metric also axisymmetric, which could reduce another equation to first order or eliminate it entirely?  By the way, how many cycles in `x - y` do you need to compute to obtain a useful answer?

Comment: I have now two Killing fields: $K = \partial_{t}+\frac{\sqrt{c^{2}+b^{2}}}{c}\partial_{z}$ and $H=\partial_{t} +\sqrt{c^{2}+b^{2}}(x\partial_{y} - y\partial_{x})$. Constants (using the Minkowski metric) would be: $const_{1} = - \dot{t} +\frac{\sqrt{c^{2}+b^{2}}}{c}\dot{z}$ and $-\dot{t} + \sqrt{c^{2}+b^{2}}(\dot{y} - \dot{x}) = const_{2}$

Comment: I am however afraid the behaviour of the solution will change (e.x. long-term drift towards z=0) if I use the constants of motion using the Minkowski metric - these effects could stem from nonlinearity.The metric is not axisymmetric, unfortunately - whether in cartesian or cylindrical coordinates there is explicit dependence on $\phi$. I will upload the rest of the code (explicit expressions and such) on pastebin - is this convenient for you?

Comment: To be clear I am interested in knowing any first integrals of the actual ODEs in the question.  I presume from your comments that constants based on the Minkowski metric are only approximate constants of the motion.  Approximate constants may be of use in understanding the orbits, but there are not so useful in solving the equations of motions themselves.  Is it possible to obtain the two first integrals exactly?  Putting the complete set of equations in pastebin or GitHub would be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I added links to pastebin - the codes for the calculations in cartesian and cylindrical coordinates, along with the expressions for the constants of motion. The two first integrals of motion (I presume that is what you asked about) are in the third link. In order to recreate my advisor results, I would need to observe two features of the trajectory (under suitable initial conditions): on a smaller scale (time from 0 to 1) the small circular oscillations in the x-y plane (about 4-5 of them) and on a bigger scale(time from 0 to 250), slow oscillations around the z=0 axis (drift).

Comment: How does your advisor solve the system in _Maple_? `dsolve`, or with self-made algorithm? If the latter, can you share some details?

Comment: Thank you for the code in cylindrical coordinates and for the constants of motion.  I ran the code as given and used it to evaluate the "constants", which varied at the same rate as rho and with about 1/2 its amplitude.  Something is wrong here.  I can send you my notebook, if you provide an email address.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I believe he used dsolve. I will ask him on Monday for more details - either way, he is still investigating his code and looking for possible problems I might have with mine. Can I share my email address in some way that does not reveal it too publicly? Like through a private message, though I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: There's no private message in this site. Discussing _Mathematica_ only in public is also my personal persistence, so that the discussion may help future visitors.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I seem unable to send you a message - is this a correct email adress?

Comment: Yes, it is. - bbgodfrey@ieee.org